# Webservice is not working anymore after changed firewall hardware (Dell sonicwall)

Tags: wcf, firewall

We have built for a customer websiteB in c# asp.net. There is also another website in php which is builded by another company. This is websiteA. The enduser is try to log in on websiteA. Underwater there is a request to a webservice on websiteB with username/password as parameters. WebsiteB try to get authenticate the credentials and return a message. WebsiteA is running on some server of another company. WebsiteB is running on our server in the datacenter. This scenario was always working!

No we have changed the firewall hardware in our datacenter. We have now Dell SonicWall. In the beginning the certificates were not working of our webservice. We have fix this. When you run our webservice in the browser the certifcate is OK (there is no red background in the url).

This is the url of my webservice:

https://service.myCompany.com/PortalService.svc

I ask the other company to give me some logging or an exception from there side. They do not get an exception. They got an empty array. They have printed some logging for me after a request:

[image]

We have also enabled the logging on the webservice. This is the logging after trying to login on websiteA.

Request to webservice:

```
<MessageLogTraceRecord>
<HttpRequest xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace">
<Method>POST</Method>
<QueryString></QueryString>
<WebHeaders>
<Connection>Keep-Alive</Connection>
<Content-Length>574</Content-Length>
<Content-Type>text/xml;charset=UTF-8</Content-Type>
<Accept>*/*</Accept>
<Authorization>Basic bWlqbnNlaF9uZXRieXRlczojbjN0Ynl0MzU=</Authorization>
<Host>service.MyCompany.com</Host>
<User-Agent>Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1</User-Agent>
<SOAPAction>"http://schemas.MyCompany.com/SecurityService/SecurityService/LoginUsernamePassword"</SOAPAction>
</WebHeaders>
</HttpRequest>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:test="http://schemas.MyCompany.com/SecurityService">
<soapenv:Header>
<To soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">https://mycompanyapp01.dmz.mycompany.local/SecurityService.svc</To>
<Action soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://schemas.MyCompany.com/SecurityService/SecurityService/LoginUsernamePassword</Action>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<test:LoginUsernamePassword>
<test:Username><![CDATA[testuser@mycompany.com]]></test:Username>
<test:Password><![CDATA[#test!]]></test:Password>
<test:ReturnToken>true</test:ReturnToken>
<test:ReturnProfile>true</test:ReturnProfile>
<test:ReturnRoles>true</test:ReturnRoles>
</test:LoginUsernamePassword>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
</MessageLogTraceRecord>
```

Response from webservice:

```
<MessageLogTraceRecord>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://schemas.MyCompany.com/SecurityService/SecurityService/LoginUsernamePasswordResponse</Action>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
<LoginUsernamePasswordResponse xmlns="http://schemas.MyCompany.com/SecurityService">
<LoginUsernamePasswordResult xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.MyCompany.com/datacontracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<d4p1:Token>PJ%2bNtW0Kpy%2frd945r3Q0ziQpoax%2bNIiPNXC8obx%2fl73D2MPTvwFA9TqDtHNzXPq7</d4p1:Token>
<d4p1:UserProfile>
<d4p1:DisplayNameFormal>Test</d4p1:DisplayNameFormal>
<d4p1:DisplayNameInformal>Test</d4p1:DisplayNameInformal>
<d4p1:Email>test@mycompany.com</d4p1:Email>
<d4p1:IsErkendAdviseur>false</d4p1:IsErkendAdviseur>
<d4p1:UserID>testuser@mycompany.com</d4p1:UserID>
</d4p1:UserProfile>
<d4p1:UserRoles xmlns:d5p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<d5p1:string>Test Medewerker</d5p1:string>
</d4p1:UserRoles>
</LoginUsernamePasswordResult>
</LoginUsernamePasswordResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
</MessageLogTraceRecord>
```

I have also started the wcf client tool (wcfTestClient.exe). I add the webservice url (https://service.myCompany.com/PortalService.svc). I got this exception:

```
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from https://service.MyCompany.com/SecurityService.svc?wsdl
If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address. For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange 

Error URI: https://service.MyCompany.com/SecurityService.svc?wsdl Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://service.MyCompany.com/SecurityService.svc?wsdl'. 

The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="service.MyCompany.com"'. 
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.HTTP GET Error URI: https://service.MyCompany.com/SecurityService.svc?wsdl 

The document was understood, but it could not be processed. - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved. - There was an error downloading 'https://myCompanyapp01.dmz.myCompany.local/SecurityService.svc?wsdl=wsdl0'. - The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. - The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

Why do I see the intern url in the exception while I testing the public url:

intern url: https://myCompanyapp01.dmz.myCompany.local/SecurityService.svc?wsdl
public url: https://service.MyCompany.com/SecurityService.svc?wsdl

The public url has a certificate. The intern url not. When you try the intern url you got a red background in the browser.

I think this whole problem is our firewall. I think there is some restricted option on SOAP outbound messages. Because websiteA which is doing the request dont get an exception. They get also an answer, but it is empty. So it looks like the firewall has make it empty.

What do you think of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your WSDL is referencing/including files on the internal app server. Try using a flattened wsdl.